# OpenCV cv::Mat causing potential memory leak with std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, matrix, stdvector

As it stands right now im trying to save an entire list of images in the form of cv::Mats inside of a vector for later processing. Right now I have something that looks like this:

```
do
{
 image = readimage();
 cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat((length, width, CV_8UC4, image));
 cv::Mat temp = mat.clone();
 saved_images.push_back();

 mat.release();
 temp.release();
 freeimagememory(image);
}
while(hasimage);
```

This actually works. For exceptionally small lists of images it will store them just fine. However as I get to large amounts of images the program consistently crashes saying Abort() was called, and upon inspection it says it's throwing a cv::exception.

Does anyone know why this is? I've thought about changing the vector to a vector of pointers to cv::Mats in order to save space (cloning seems expensive) but I'm not sure how well that will work.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT1:** The exact error being thrown is failed to allocated X bytes. I assume this is because it's eating up all of the available memory somehow (even though I'm sitting on 8 gigs of memory and definitely have memory free).

**EDIT2:**

The below code also seems to work.

```
std::vector<cv::Mat*> ptrvec;
do{

 image.readimage();
 ptrvec.push_back(new cv::Mat((length, width, CV_8UC4, image)));
 freeimagememory(image);
}
while(hasimage);
```

This one doesn't have a problem with memory (I can push all the images I want to it) but I get an access violation when I try to do

```
cv::imshow("Test Window", *ptrvec[0]);
```

**EDIT3:**

Is there a chance I'm hitting the upper limit of 32 bit? I'm more than capable of recompiling this into a 64 bit project.

Comment: what is the cv::exception thrown? How many images are stored in a vector when the program crashes?

Comment: ~3000 are stored. When it breaks and I click "break" it leads me to the code for new.

Comment: The system is probably out of memory. What is the size of the images?

Comment: ~2 gb altogether. I figure it's passed the allowed maximum memory of a 32 bit executable. Is this correct?

Comment: It could use more space than 2GB, since your vector of `Mat` objects is stored in memory as uncompressed data. What is the size of the picture, like in height vs length? For example a 640 pixels by 480 pixels color (RGB) image will occupy approximately `640 x 480 x 3 = 921,600 Bytes ~ 1 MB` in memory.

Comment: 800 x 600. So it would occupy around 1.33 mb of space x 3000...yeah that seems like my problem. Will that pointer solution help or am I stuck rewriting the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be running out of memory when you store 3000 color images 800 x 600 in a vector. Storing Mat pointers in memory will not solve your problem, since the data is still allocated in RAM.

Check whether there is enough memory in your system to store all the images. If not you can upload images in batches, for example, process the first 500 images, then process the next 500 images, etc.

In your program you allocate the vector on the *stack*. Allocating on the *heap* is recommended when you need a large block of memory (your case). So can try to allocate the vector on the heap instead (provided that you have enough memory to store the vector). See, [stack vs heap](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html), or [this cpp-tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/) for more information.

Comment: I'm pretty sure vectors are implemented using dynamic memory, which should be the heap right?

Comment: Yes, good point, I think you are correct. The vector object itself can be either on the stack or the heap. However the memory that is used to store the vector's elements is always allocated dynamically on the heap.